# How can I check the cookie in the Safari?

Tags: safari

How can I find the panel for the website cookies in Safari?
I can't seem to find it in Safari's Network panel:

[image]

How do I check website cookies in Safari?

---

**EDIT**

If I use Firefox browser's Firebug, I can see a tab for cookies:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose the storage tab, second from the right with the database icon (three stacked ovals).

[image]